# Android DownloadManager error Unsuccessful

Tags: android, download

I'm working with Android downloadmanager. I got this error when passing url to downloadmanager. It's said that Download unsuccessfully, But I tried to use my browser then paste url . It's response file mp3. I don't know why downloadmanager did not recognize file to download. 
Here is example URL to test:

```
http://htstar.design/mp3zing.php?q=320&link=http://mp3.zing.vn/bai-hat/Tired-Alan-Walker-Gavin-James/ZW7FA7WA.html
```

Update Here is my method download:

```
private void downloadFile(String url, String name) {
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setTitle(name.replace(ext, ""));
    request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
    request.setDescription(name);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Music", name);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    fabOpenDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: what does `DownloadManager#query()` return?

Comment: I have just updated my code in above. Could you please check my code out and provide me with some advice?

Comment: what does `DownloadManager#query()` return?

Comment: I have not added this line in this code. What's that line for? I wonder about that?

Comment: I log  receiver code is 400.